# Eclipse J2EE: add external class file

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to use 'Add External Class Folder' to add some .class files in the build path. But I got some error as below

> An internal error occurred during: "Setting build path". found:
>   /.org.eclipse.jdt.core.external.folders/.link4/com/util.

Confused.

Thanks

Comment: maybe you could provide more details such as what eclipse you are using, what steps can reproduce your error, things like that

Comment: 3.7.2 for Eclipse. The project is for dynamic web. I remember I added its upper path (e.g. /com/) since there are four sub directories (/com/sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4). But Eclipse still complained they couldn't resolve the import. So I tried to add sub directories in, then the error happened.

Comment: At first time, I tried to edit the original path, then did some actions like editing, added another sub directory in, then got the error as well. Then I removed all of them, tried to add a sub directory in, but the same error happened again.

Comment: I did a work around. I created a class folder in the project and imported them in, Then use 'Add Class Folder' to include those class files.